# AngularJS Route Uncaught object in v 1.2.15 But not in v 1.0.1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I've been trying a ng-route example which works in AngularJS version 1.0.1 but not working in version 1.2.15. I did added the dependency angular-route.js but still getting uncaught object error. The following is my example. It consists of 4 files (index.html, page.html, chapter.html, and main.html).

If you comment out 1.2.15/angular.min.js, angular-route.js and .module('testNgRoute', ['ngRoute']) and uncomment 1.0.1/angular.min.js and .module('testNgRoute', []). It will work.

page.html contains only one line "This is page.html"

chapter.html contains only one line "This is chapter.html"

main.html contains only one line "This is main.html"

**This is my index.html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testNgRoute">

    <title>Test ng-route</title>

    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>Test ng-route</h1>
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
    </body>

    <!--it works when I use this version of angularJS-->
    <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>-->

    <!--it didn't work when I use this version of angularJS-->
    <!--  According to the documentation, I should include angular-route.js-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular-route.js"><script>

    <script>
        angular
            //it works when I use v1.0.1 and without including any dependencies.
            //.module('testNgRoute', [])
            //it didn't work when I use v1.2.15 with the "ngRoute" dependencies
            .module('testNgRoute', ['ngRoute'])
            .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

                "use strict";
                $routeProvider
                    .when('/page', {
                        templateUrl: "page.html" 
                    })
                    .when('/chapter', {
                        templateUrl: 'chapter.html'
                    })
                    .when('/', {
                        templateUrl: 'main.html'
                    });

            }]);
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Properly close the script tag that is loading angular.route.js.

Comment: You are right, that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rookie mistake. The angular-route.js script tag is not close properly. Thanks tasseKATT for spotting it.

False alarm. I've tested it and it is working correctly.